# conversion from testng to jar in java shows error

Tags: java, testng

I have converted the testng file to jar by creating a class Main and have main method inside it

```
package uatFramework;

import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;
import org.testng.TestNG;

public class Mainone{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { RMS_Login.class });
    testng.addListener(tla);
    testng.run();
    }
}
```

But the RMS_Login class extends BeforeSfterSuite class too. 
Now when i run the main as java app->The browser opened and closed successfully appears but the page doesnot load and i get the error for:

```
@Parameters({"sUsername","sPassword","sUrl"})       
    public void uatRMSLoginTest(String sUsername, String sPassword,java.lang.String sUrl) throws InterruptedException, IOException
      {       
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file,true);
        String filename= "screenshots";
        File filepath =new File(folderpath+"/" +filename);
        filepath.mkdirs();
        if (System.getenv("sURL") != null) 
        {  
           ....
        }
 }
```

as org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'sUsername' is required by @Test on method uatRMSLoginTest but has not been marked @Optional or defined
    at uatFramework.Mainone.main(Mainone.java:13) ie for testng.run in main method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that its not injecting the required parameters which your `@Test` method is expecting via `@Parameters` annotation.

Here's a code, that contains working code.

```
import org.testng.ITestNGListener;
import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;
import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

import java.util.Collections;

public class Mainone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();

        XmlSuite xmlSuite = new XmlSuite();
        xmlSuite.getParameters().put("sUsername", "admin");
        xmlSuite.getParameters().put("sPassword", "admin");
        xmlSuite.getParameters().put("sUrl", "http://localhost");
        xmlSuite.setName("Sample_Suite");
        XmlTest xmlTest = new XmlTest(xmlSuite);
        xmlTest.setName("Sample_Test");
        xmlTest.setClasses(Collections.singletonList(new XmlClass(RMS_Login.class)));
        testng.addListener((ITestNGListener) tla);
        testng.setXmlSuites(Collections.singletonList(xmlSuite));
        testng.run();
    }

    public static class RMS_Login {

        @Parameters({"sUsername", "sPassword", "sUrl"})
        @Test
        public void uatRMSLoginTest(String sUsername, String sPassword, String sUrl) {
            //Since I don't know what this method is supposed to do,
            //Just printing them out.
            System.err.println("UserName " + sUsername);
            System.err.println("Password " + sPassword);
            System.err.println("URL " + sUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output

```
UserName admin
Password admin
URL http://localhost

===============================================
Sample_Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: thank you so much! But should i create a different class for the main function?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you do that. I was only showing you a fixed version of your code. It's up to you to decide how you want to consume it.

Comment: instead of using custsom report i want to use some other style say extentreport how would i use it for this code?